# Oracle 19c on Oracle Linux 8, dbora start script ONLY starting when chkconfig sets it to level S99. Any other level like S98, fails to start on reboot

Tags: init.d, oracle-linux, chkconfig

I'm running Oracle 19c on Oracle Linux 8, `dbora` start script ONLY starting when `chkconfig` sets it to level S99. Any other level like S98, fails to start on reboot.  Regardless of the `chkconfig` level, the script will run successfully, manually with `service dbora start/stop`.  If it's set as level 99 (see below):

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/dbora
# chkconfig: 345 99 10
```

it then will be running after I reboot, successfully.  This seems only to work when it's set to 99.

However, I have another application that needs to launch at startup, also with `init.d` scripts, that requires to start AFTER the DB has started.

So, I tried `chkconfig --del dbora`.  Then changed the `chkconfig` header from 99 to 98. Then `chkconfig --add dbora`.  This replaced the previous `/etc/rc(3/4/5).d/S99dbora`  files with `/etc/rc(3/4/5).d/S98dbora`.

I then ran `chkconfig --add engine`, and the engine script with the following header does show up in the rc3/4/5 directories as S99engine:

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/engine
# chkconfig: 345 99 11
```

However, when I reboot now, the DB does not start up.  It doesn't seem to matter what level I set for the DB startup script, but it will ONLY work when at 99?  Is this a limitation to the Oracle 19c `dbora` script for some reason, that it needs to be 99?  Since that's the last/highest level I can set, how do I get another `init.d` script to run after it?

I've done LOTS/hours of searching on here.  Everything just seems to say to use `chkconfig` to change the order of startup...but, I can't find anything saying why it would ONLY start at 99 and why I can't have anything startup after it.

Comment: Linux does not use `init` anymore. It uses `systemd`. See here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342860/oracle-linux-7-autostart-oracle-with-init-d

Comment: http://www.moreajays.com/2020/11/database-auto-startup-in-oracle-19c.html?m=1